# Connect to External Oracle database using ksqlDB running in Docker container

Tags: oracle, docker, ksqldb

I am trying to connect to External Oracle database using ksqlDB running in docker container on my Windows 10 machine. I have gone through the tutorials mentioned on the ksqlDB website and managed to run ksqlDB using below docker-compose file. Now, I need to create JDBC connector to connect to EXTERNAL ORACLE database(not inside container). As most of the available tutorials are on the Postgres database running inside container, I am a little bit confused about connectivity with external databases. I have mentioned one template for connector below. Please suggest how can I modify it based on my Oracle database configuration?

Suppose, Oracle database configuration are as mentioned below on my local machine :

```
HOST = dev-db.com
PORT = 1522
SERVICE NAME = dv06.db.com
```

**Connector template for Postgres:**

```
CREATE SOURCE CONNECTOR jdbc_source WITH (
  'connector.class'          = 'io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector',
  'connection.url'           = 'jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres',
  'connection.user'          = 'postgres',
  'connection.password'      = 'password',
  'topic.prefix'             = 'jdbc_',
  'table.whitelist'          = 'driver_profiles',
  'mode'                     = 'incrementing',
  'numeric.mapping'          = 'best_fit',
  'incrementing.column.name' = 'driver_id',
  'key'                      = 'driver_id',
  'key.converter'            = 'org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.IntegerConverter');
```

***Docker-compose.yml***

```
---
version: '2'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.4.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

  ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/ksqldb-server:0.7.0
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8088
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:9092
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: "true"
      KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_WORKER_CONFIG: "/connect/connect.properties"
      KSQL_CONNECT_GROUP_ID: "ksql-connect-cluster"
      KSQL_CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:9092"
      KSQL_CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
      KSQL_CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      KSQL_CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
      KSQL_CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      KSQL_CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: "ksql-connect-configs"
      KSQL_CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: "ksql-connect-offsets"
      KSQL_CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: "ksql-connect-statuses"
      KSQL_CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KSQL_CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KSQL_CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KSQL_CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/kafka/plugins"
    volumes:
      - ./confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-5.4.0:/usr/share/kafka/plugins/jdbc 

  ksqldb-cli:
    image: confluentinc/ksqldb-cli:0.7.0
    container_name: ksqldb-cli
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - ksqldb-server
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    tty: true
```

Comment: I think this question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach you need to change your connection.url to point to the url of your oracle database instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you need is to know the format of the `connection.url` to use, then the Oracle docs are your friend here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDPJD/getconn.htm#TDPJD138

For example, the following may work for you:

`'connection.url'           = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@dev-db.com:1522',`

Of course, you'll also need to update the username, password and other details about the tables and their keys that you want to import using the connector too.